# REGEXP_SUBSTR Assistence

Tags: regex, oracle, oracle10g

Regular expression are by far my weak spot.
I'm trying to break down the following strings

```
Node 51 Path 1 Route 4
Node 51A Path 12 Route 3
Node 5 Path 12 Route 2
Node 7B Path 1 Route 1
```

What I need is the Node , the Node's letter , the Path and the Route.

I'm having trouble extracting the node's letter. The node's letter is a single non digit character that will always follow the Node's number with no white spaces.

for rows 2 & 4

```
Node 51A Path 12 Route 3 - Nodes letter is A
Node 5 Path 12 Route 2 - Nodes letter is NULL 
Node 7B Path 1 Route 1- Nodes letter is B
```

So far ,

```
with gen as (
    select 'Node 51 Path 1 Route 4' x from dual union all 
    select 'Node 51A Path 12 Route 3' x from dual union all 
    select 'Node 5 Path 12 Route 2' x from dual union all 
    select 'Node 7B Path 1 Route 1' x from dual
) 
select  x , 
        regexp_substr(x, '(\d+)',1,1) as Node , 
        regexp_substr(x, '(\d+)',1,2) as Path , 
        regexp_substr(x, '(\d+)',1,3) as Route
from    gen  

X                        NODE   PATH   ROUTE
------------------------ ------ ------ -------
Node 51 Path 1 Route 4   51     1      4
Node 51A Path 12 Route 3 51     12     3
Node 5 Path 12 Route 2   5      12     2
Node 7B Path 1 Route 1   7      1      1
```

Oracle 10gR2.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
with gen as (
    select 'Node 51 Path 1 Route 4' x from dual union all 
    select 'Node 51A Path 12 Route 3' x from dual union all 
    select 'Node 5 Path 12 Route 2' x from dual union all 
    select 'Node 7B Path 1 Route 1' x from dual
) 
select  x , 
        regexp_substr(x, '\d+') as Node, 
        regexp_replace(regexp_substr(x, '\d+\S*'),'\d+') as NodeLetter , 
        regexp_substr(x, '\d+',1,2) as Path , 
        regexp_substr(x, '\d+',1,3) as Route
from    gen
```

Comment: So you extracted the entire Node and removed any digit. Nice. Thanks.